# How to remove corrupted group

Tags: 2013, groups, sharepoint-on-prem

We are using SP2013 on-premise. I have discovered a corrupted group that I wish to re-create. I cant go to its setting-page from the gui, I get an error page (with message "Cant find the group")

When I try to remove it with powershell, it says "Group cannot be found" and when I try to create a group with same name, it says that "the name is already in use"

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to execute this powershell and check "IsHiddenInUI" tag ?

```
$web = get-spweb "siteurl"  $group =$web.SiteGroups["groupname"]  $group
```

Comment: hmm, I get an empty string, When I try to write-host it. (I tested with another group to verify, and for that group I get "False")

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to get all groups and check if corrupt group is found. 
Also try to delete group through group ID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!. When I list all sitegroups in powershell, it does not list this Group. I can get its ID (got it from gui in Query string), but when I try to delete it by ID, I get the same error message "Group cannot be found"